# Installing Windows 8 from USB stick on a computer with only FreeDOS installed

Tags: windows-8, boot, usb, bios

I just bought an Asus G750JX and it has no Windows installed on it only the BIOS.
When I open it I get three options:

1. Load FreeDOS with maximum RAM free using EMM386
2. Load FreeDOS including HIMEM XMS-memory driver
3. Load FreeDOS without drivers

I got the option to press:

F5=Bypass startup files
F8=Confirm each line of CONFIG.SYS/AUTOEXEC.BAT

I managed to get into the BIOS, but I can’t seem to find the bootable stick I have inserted. I seem to have these three boot options:

- P2: Slimtype DVD A DS8A9SH
- P4: ST750LMooo-1EJ16G
- Atheros Boot Agent

My USB stick is an HP stick; I used it before to install Windows, and in the BIOS, I always found something that contained the word “HP”.

I am running out of options. How can I start the installer for Windows?

Comment: Burn it to a DVD and try to boot from that.

Comment: Go to the "Security" section and ensure that the usb ports are not locked in the "i/o interface security" sub menu. Might as well check "secure boot control" sub section as well.